# Why does crippling pain exist?

Tags: human-biology, brain, pain

Some kinds of trauma can cause pain so severe that it makes you unable to move or do anything at all.
It may put you out of action and unable to help yourself because of how excruciating it is.

Although I understand that pain is necessary to alert the brain that something is wrong and need to be fixed, I imagine it like an alarm going off alerting about trauma. But a crippling pain would be like a deafening siren hooked up to your ear making you unable to do anything to correct the problem, instead it might send you into a shock. It would be total disaster which could prevent you from taking any step about it. So, **why does excruciating pain exist?** Or in other words, why has this feature not gone extinct during the course of evolution in spite of its harmful effects?

Comment: Pain tells your body that something is wrong and needs to be fixed. Crippling pain is telling you that the "something" is an immediate danger to life or limb, and needs to be paid attention to ***NOW***. Continuing on with your normal activities will be severely detrimental to your health.

Comment: @MattDMo but what good is it if you can't do anything more than moaning, rolling and eventually dying from shock while if it wasnt crippling you could have done something to save yourselves like moving to safety or applying pressure to bleeding wound etc that would have avoided death

Comment: To this point, I would like to tell you an incident which I saw once on TV (so I don't have reference for it). Once a mountain climber fell from height ~300m straight on a rock. Her hip joint, both knee joints, and some bones broke & she fainted. When she was unconscious, her brain decided that the pain is too excruciating to do anything and should be switched off (by endorphins). When she woke, she didn't feel any pain and somehow reached paramedic camp. When she reached, then she started feeling pain again.